# RN sound Level switch the silence -160 to 0

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm

I wanna use react native sound level on my app. Everything is working but the silence start to -160 (soundArray). I wanna start the silence at 0 to dont have a negative result.

i'm trying to start the state to 0 but it doesn't works.

Any ideas ?

my states :

```
class Decibels extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
 
      soundArray: [-160],
      soundCapture: false,
      DateMatch: true,
      sport: {clubs: []},
      tempsRestants: 0,
    };
    this.interval = null;
  }
```

also my function

```
  startMatch = () => {
  
    const club = this.state.sport.clubs[0];
    let dateMatch = new Date(club.dateMatch).getTime();

    let dateMatchStop = new Date(club.dateMatchStop).getTime();
    let today = Date.now();

    if (today >= dateMatch && today <= dateMatchStop) {
      this.setState({soundCapture: true}),
        RNSoundLevel.start(),
        (RNSoundLevel.onNewFrame = (data) => {
          this.setState({soundArray: data.value});
          this.PostDecibels();
        });
    }
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      let today = Date.now();
      let finMatch = dateMatchStop;

      if (today >= finMatch) {
        RNSoundLevel.stop();
        Alert.alert('titre', 'terminé');
        this.setState({soundCapture: false});
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
    }, 5000);
  };
```

Thanks a lot for your help !